# htaccess - The custom 404 error page is not working properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, file, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

**EDIT: This question has been solved. Please see my answer**.

I have the file `.htaccess` that contains only the following line (I have added a custom 404 error page)

```
ErrorDocument 404 404.php
```

This is the code of the page `404.php`:

```
<?php echo("file not found")?>
```

The problem is that if i type in my browser for example the url `http://127.0.0.1/www/website/this_file_does_not_exist` the page shows this line:

```
404.php
```

In other words, i see only the filename of the custom 404 error page instead of the content of the 404 error page.
I have already searched on stackoverflow for a solution without success.
How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

From [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html):

> The syntax of the ErrorDocument directive is:
>
> ```
> ErrorDocument <3-digit-code> <action>
> ```
>
> where the action will be treated as:
>
> 1. A local URL to redirect to (if the action begins with a "/").
> 2. An external URL to redirect to (if the action is a valid URL).
> 3. Text to be displayed (if none of the above). The text must be
>      wrapped in quotes (") if it consists of more than one word.

In other words, if you're going to use a local URL it has to begin with a "/":

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Comment: i have tried with your solution, now if i type an url that does not exist Apache redirects the url to 404.php . This is not what i need. I need to display the content of the page 404.php without a redirect!

Comment: According to the documentation, this should be an "internal redirect" (no URL change). See, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument